# Validating Mandatory String values in JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have below sample schema. I need to ensure that there should be at least one occurrence of "name": "This is Mandatory" in the json file

Is it possible to achieve this ? Kindly help.

```
   "SchemaList": {
      "type": "array",      
      "additionalItems": false,
      "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/Schema1" }          
        },
   "Schema1": {
      "type": "object",         
      "properties": {
        "description": { "type": "string" },
        "name": { "type": "string" }        
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest draft (Draft 6) introduces a new keyword [`"contains"`](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.14) , with which you can express that a given schema should match at least one element in the array. You can use it this way:

```
{
    "SchemaList": {
        "additionalItems": false,
        "contains": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "const": "This is Mandatory"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "name"
            ]
        },
        "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Schema1"
        },
        "type": "array"
    }
}
```

But bear in mind that [**the latest draft version of json-schema has only a very few implementations**](http://json-schema.org/implementations.html) , so depending on the library you use, the `"contains"` keyword might not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot @erosb
This is exactly what I was looking for. I did try "contains" earlier but haven`t realised that it is valid from v6. Btw, I am using this in Swagger 2.0 (which uses V4). Anyways this is very helpful. Have a great Time :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link for more details: http://json-schema.org/example1.html

```
{
"SchemaList": {
    "type": "array",
    "additionalItems": false,
    "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Schema1"
    }
},
"Schema1": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "description": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
},
"required": ["name"]
}
```

Comment: In the above example, it is mandatory to declare "name" but it cannot enforce the value of name. 

I cannot use enum because I need dynamic values for name and it should mandate name: "ThisIsMandatory" to occur atleast once.

To be more clear I need to validate the value of the name.

Comment: You are trying get the name value & need to do something with it?