# How can I specify in a json schema that a certain property is mandatory and also must contain a specific value?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to create several json schemas for different scenarios.

For scenario 1 I would like to specify that:

a) The property "draftenabled" must have the value true.

b) the property "draftenabled" does exist.

I have checked this post
[Validating Mandatory String values in JSON Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996855/validating-mandatory-string-values-in-json-schema)
and tried the following

I tried to validate this json

```
{
    "$schema": "./test-schema.json",
    "draftenabled": false,
    "prefix": "hugo"
}
```

with this schema test-schema.json that I had created in Visual Studio Code.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "properties": {
        "$schema": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "draftenabled": {
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "prefix": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "additionalItems": false,
    "contains": {
        "properties": {
            "draftenabled": {
                "const": true
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "draftenabled"
        ]
    }
}
```

I would have expected an error since the value for draftenabled is false rather than true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is some confusion around how the keywords apply to instances (data) of different types.

- `properties` only applies to objects
- `additionalItems` and `contains` only apply to arrays

Since your instance is an object, `additionalItems` and `contains` will be ignored.

Based on your description of what you want, I would do something like the following:

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "properties": {
        "$schema": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "draftenabled": {
            "const": "true"
        },
        "prefix": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "draftenabled"
    ]
}
```

This moves the definitions you have in the `contains` into the main schema.  You got that bit right, just in the wrong place.

---

You also mention that this is a "scenario 1."  If there are other scenarios, I suggest creating schemas like this for each scenario then wrapping all of them together in a `oneOf` or `anyOf`:

```json
{
    "oneOf": [
        { <scenario 1> },
        { <scenario 2> },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: You are totally right. I was looking for having a mandatory property in an object that should have constant value.